# Spring websocket establishing connection is stuck at 'opening connection'

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am using `spring-boot-websocket` (`spring-boot` version `1.5.10`) in my project. I have configured it as below,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport
        implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Value( "${rabbitmq.host}" )
    private String rabbitmqHost;
    @Value( "${rabbitmq.stomp.port}" )
    private int rabbitmqStompPort;
    @Value( "${rabbitmq.username}" )
    private String rabbitmqUserName;
    @Value( "${rabbitmq.password}" )
    private String rabbitmqPassword;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker( MessageBrokerRegistry registry )
    {
        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue").setRelayHost(rabbitmqHost).setRelayPort(rabbitmqStompPort)
                .setSystemLogin(rabbitmqUserName).setSystemPasscode(rabbitmqPassword);
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints( StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry )
    {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public WebSocketHandler subProtocolWebSocketHandler()
    {
        return new CustomSubProtocolWebSocketHandler(clientInboundChannel(), clientOutboundChannel());
    }

    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport( WebSocketTransportRegistration registry )
    {
        super.configureWebSocketTransport(registry);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configureMessageConverters( List<MessageConverter> messageConverters )
    {
        return super.configureMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel( ChannelRegistration registration )
    {
        super.configureClientInboundChannel(registration);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientOutboundChannel( ChannelRegistration registration )
    {
        super.configureClientOutboundChannel(registration);
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers( List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers )
    {
        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
    }

    @Override
    public void addReturnValueHandlers( List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> returnValueHandlers )
    {
        super.addReturnValueHandlers(returnValueHandlers);
    }

}

public class CustomSubProtocolWebSocketHandler extends SubProtocolWebSocketHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomSubProtocolWebSocketHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserCommons userCommons;

    CustomSubProtocolWebSocketHandler(MessageChannel clientInboundChannel,
                                      SubscribableChannel clientOutboundChannel) {
        super(clientInboundChannel, clientOutboundChannel);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("************************************************************************************************************************New webSocket connection was established: {}", session);
        String token = session.getUri().getQuery().replace("token=", "");
        try
        {
            String user = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(TokenConstant.SECRET)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TokenConstant.TOKEN_PREFIX, "")).getBody().getSubject();
            Optional<UserModel> userModelOptional = userCommons.getUserByEmail(user);
            if( !userModelOptional.isPresent() )
            {
                LOGGER.error(
                        "************************************************************************************************************************Invalid token is passed with web socket request");
                throw new DataException(GeneralConstants.EXCEPTION, "Invalid user", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            LOGGER.error(GeneralConstants.ERROR, e);
        }
        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus closeStatus) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.error("************************************************************************************************************************webSocket connection was closed");
        LOGGER.error("Reason for closure {} Session: {} ", closeStatus.getReason(),session.getId() );
        super.afterConnectionClosed(session, closeStatus);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception) throws Exception {

        LOGGER.error("************************************************************************************************************************Connection closed unexpectedly");
        LOGGER.error(GeneralConstants.ERROR, exception);
        super.handleTransportError(session, exception);
    }
}
```

From the client-side, I am creating a `SockJS` object to establish the connection,

```
let url = `/ws?token=${localStorage.getItem("access_token")}`;
        // Web Socket connection
        /* eslint-disable */
        let sockJS = new SockJS(url);
        let stompClient = Stomp.over(sockJS);
        debugger
        this.setState({
            stompObject : stompClient,
        });
```

But the connection is not getting established consistently, most of the times it is stuck at `Opening the connection`, in the backend log, I can see the connection getting established and a session is created. But, in the browser console, I can see client-side sending message to the server but the server is not acknowledging the message.

[image]

[image]

Sometimes, when I refresh the browser for 10-15 times, the connection is getting established successfully. Is there any mistake in my configuration?

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried to comment out after connection established part of your code? @Naanavanalla

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can "hit refresh 10 or 15 times and then get a connection," I'm curious if you dealing with a cookie issue?  I know Chrome is famous for that sort of thing.  Anyway close out all browser windows and stop the browser, then start the browser, and tell it to clear browsing history and then attempt the connection.  Also, be SURE you read the version of the spring-boot docs for the version of spring-boot you are that you are actually using, and also specify the SB version in your questions and when looking for answers.